# How can i use symfony 3 with mariadb and doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mariadb, symfony-3.2

How can i use symfony 3 with mariadb?

But i want to use doctrine also but i did not see any useful information on
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#sqlanywhere

So please guide or provide proper article link thanks.

Comment: try dump($this->getDoctrine()->getConnection()); and look and the private property platform. what class is it?

Comment: Dude, configuration for mariadb is exactly the same as for the mysql

Comment: [MariaDB is a binary drop in replacement for MySQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/), just like Percona. However each database platform has their own technical specifications and limitations. ie. MariaDB JSON support is a TEXT field, where MySQL would be JSON. MariaDB will tranlate most MySQL specific function calls automatically to be compatible with how MariaDB functions.

Answer (score 11):

If you get doctrine:schema:update to show the same migrations again and again, consider adding this to your config:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        server_version: 'mariadb-X.X.X'
```

Replacing X.X.X with the real version of mariadb installed on the executing machine.

Comment: Just an extra information: GitHub discussion about the mariadb prefix for the server version: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/2985#issuecomment-378595588

Answer (score 1):

The mysql-client package also works with MariaDB server. You can see the Version Details here.
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/the-mariadb-library/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/

Answer (score 0):

HI its similar to mysql configuration

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: test # your database name
    database_user: root # mysql username
    database_password: test123 # mysql password
```

In your **config.yml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
```

Comment: yes i see but any way i can check in symfony controller that i am using maria db not mysql.

Comment: maria db and mysql are both are similar configuration if not understood, can you post code

Comment: understand and worked, but and it works but i want to confirm i am connected to maria db not mysql.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the port change, 3307, check the port in MariaDB:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3307
    database_name: test # your database name
    database_user: root # mysql username
    database_password: test123 # mysql password
```