# Symfony Doctrine runs same queries

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

since the last update of my server which happened last month, I face an unusual problem with Doctrine.

When I run `doctrine:schema:update --force`, I the result "54 queries executed". The same result happens even if I don't change my entities.

When I run `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to see the queries, I can see that same queries are run. Ex :

```
ALTER TABLE artisan CHANGE creator_id creator_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE user_connection CHANGE date date DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE device CHANGE device_type device_type VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT 'ios' NOT NULL;
```

The problem is that columns are from the same type that the one changed by the query. I don't know why Doctrine want to change the type.

MariaDB version is 10.4.13 - Doctrine version is 2.5.14 - Symfony version is 2.8.42

**Entity examples :**

**Device : device_type**

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="device_type", type="string", length=500, options={ "default":"ios" })
 */
private $device_type = "ios";
```

**UserConnection : date**

```
/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $date;
```

**Artisan : Creator**

```
/**
 * @var User
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MiddlewareBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="creator_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 * })
 */
private $creator;
```

Comment: Does running "describe table artisan;" offer any clues on how creator_id is defined?

Comment: yes, but different types encounter the same problem. Creator id is :     Field Type Null Key Default Extra  - creator_id int(11) YES MUL NULL

Comment: I remember sometimes running into this sort of issue back in the early days of Symfony 2.  I would solve them by simply dropping the schema and then recreating it.  An option which I doubt you would have.  Your server upgrade presumably upgraded your mysql version which is probably what is causing the problem.  Your Symfony/Doctrine versions are very old.  Sorry but I can't offer any silver bullet to fix this.  Maybe someone else can.

Comment: thank you @Cerad. I aloso think of a problem between doctrine and mysql versions, but upgrading Doctrine is something which would be very difficult for us.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? `10.4`  does not sound like MySQL after all, but rather like MariaDB. Using that should be explicitly configured

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i use symfony 3 with mariadb and doctrine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894300/how-can-i-use-symfony-3-with-mariadb-and-doctrine)

Comment: @NicoHaase sorry about that. It's MariaDB that is 10.4.13. I tried the answer you sent me, but did not manage to change my config (Invalid platform version "mariadb-10.4.13" specified. The platform version has to be specified in the format: "<major_version>.<minor_version>.<patch_version>".) I'm still trying to fix this.

Comment: Which version of `doctrine/dbal` and related packages are you using?  `doctrine/orm:2.5.14` is pretty old and no longer maintainer, so probably you need to update it?

Comment: Doctrine/dbal is 2.6.3. I thought about an update problem, but as Symfony help tells us that a MariaDb confi parameter exists, I'm not sure the problem comes from an update (https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/configuration/doctrine.html)

Comment: As you can see on https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/releases/tag/v2.7.0, the explicit support for MariaDB has been added in `doctrine/dbal:2.7.0`

Answer (score 1):

There has been a pull request some years ago, have a look at https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/2825 - it clearly states your problem:

> Doctrine currently does not support MariaDB 10.2.7+. Schema creation/update is triggering infinite schema diffs

The code from this pull request has been included since `doctrine/dbal:2.7.0`, so you should consider updating at least that single package

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also think about a version problem, but I would like to avoid it if possible because of the complexity and the status of our application, which is stil in development.

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid"? If that is something that is fixed in a later version only, there is no other chance than updating. Also, even if your application is "in development", upgrading libraries is something that should not be too hard, it should be possible with ease when having a proper test coverage